# How do I use a Ansible Galaxy role in a task that requires root privileges?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I wrote a playbook that uses a set of roles according the suggested structure https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure

Now I want to use a Ansible Galaxy dependency for the first time and defined it in `requirements.yml` and install it in the playbook itself.

I want to call the role in my subrole task `subrole/tasks/main.yml`. As stated in the documentation (https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/postgresql) the role needs root access. In a play this is easy and only an added `become: true` is working. However in my task I need to use the `include_role` module that had this feature once, but it was removed. Now there is another option called `apply` that's documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-apply) states the same feature: `Accepts a hash of task keywords (e.g. tags, become) that will be applied to all tasks within the included role.`
But this is not working. The error message clearly states the the root privilege is missing.

```yaml
- name: use postgresql role
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: geerlingguy.postgresql
    apply:
      become: true
```

What am I doing wrong? Why was the direct way of using become like in a play removed at all? Should tasks be avoided? Questions over questions...

Comment: I can add the question when to use import_role over include_role beside the thin details named in documentation.

Comment: No features were removed from `include_role`. `include` was split into a number of discrete tasks (including `include_role` and `import_role`) so that people had to explicitly say what they wanted instead of a single directive magically behaving differently due to opaque rules, but no functionality was removed in the split. The differences between static imports and dynamic includes are clearly laid out in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-files-and-roles .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work in the first place. It is working now exactly as written here, very strange.